# How to align parallel lists

Tags: spacing, text, parcolumns

I have two lists with items of different lengths,

```
\usepackage{parcolumns}

\begin{parcolumns}{2}
    \colchunk{
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item Et ullamco veniam adipisicing dolore quis cillum cillum laboris nisi id adipisicing proident laboris consequat ut aliqua in dolor ut culpa aliquip est aliqua ut eu qui.
            \item Ut qui adipisicing dolore ea deserunt ut labore ad sed irure voluptate magna duis nulla officia consectetur sit amet.
            \item Ad elit officia fugiat laboris et ut excepteur amet sit laboris voluptate enim in dolore pariatur excepteur minim culpa commodo nostrud culpa mollit esse in eu aute esse duis ad ea adipisicing non.
        \end{enumerate}
    }
    \colchunk{
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item Incididunt incididunt veniam consectetur ullamco.
            \item Aliquip nulla qui duis.
            \item Anim officia proident.
        \end{enumerate}
    }
\end{parcolumns}
```

so when I place them each in a column, the alignment is not correct.

What I would like to obtain is something like this:

```
1. Some text    1. Long text lorem
                   ipsum dolor sit
                   amet
2. Another text 2. dolore quis cillum
                   cillum laboris
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`paracol` allows you to produce such synchronized lists, see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/484611).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{paracol}
\begin{document}
 \begin{enumerate}
    \begin{paracol}{2}
      \switchcolumn[1]* \item Et ullamco veniam adipisicing dolore quis cillum cillum laboris nisi id adipisicing proident laboris consequat ut aliqua in dolor ut culpa aliquip est aliqua ut eu qui.
      \switchcolumn[0]  \item Incididunt incididunt veniam consectetur ullamco.
      \switchcolumn[1]* \item Ut qui adipisicing dolore ea deserunt ut labore ad sed irure voluptate magna duis nulla officia consectetur sit amet.
      \switchcolumn[0]  \item Aliquip nulla qui duis.
      \switchcolumn[1]* \item Ad elit officia fugiat laboris et ut excepteur amet sit laboris voluptate enim in dolore pariatur excepteur minim culpa commodo nostrud culpa mollit esse in eu aute esse duis ad ea adipisicing non.
      \switchcolumn[0]  \item Anim officia proident.
    \end{paracol}
    \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: what is the role of the star?

Comment: @Blincer The manual say `The starred version column* does the same after synchronization and, if specified, the optional spanning text is put.` and then `The environments are almost equivalent to {\switchcolumn body \par}
{\switchcolumn*[text ] body \par}`, so my interpretation is it does the synchronization.

Comment: Absolutely perfect